# jQuery bind not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a strange problem, from the ones below only the first one works, i need to mention that both of them are in jQuery(document).ready(function(){});
There are no errors in the console.

This one works

```
    jQuery('.delete_product_line').click(function(){
            console.log('xxxxx2');
});
```

This one doesn't work

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.delete_product_line', function(){ console.log('ccccc');});
```

This is the full example, i know it does not make any sense, also the #submitAddProduct works as it should.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){



jQuery('body').on('click', '#submitAddProduct', function(){


    var interval;

    var product_id = jQuery('#add_product_product_id').val();
    var price_tax_excl = jQuery('#add_product_product_price_tax_excl').val();
    var price_tax_incl = jQuery('#add_product_product_price_tax_incl').val();
    var qty = jQuery('#add_product_product_quantity').val();
    var id_combination = 0;

    var initial_rows = jQuery('#orderProducts tbody tr').length;
    var i = 0;
    var rows = 0;

    console.log(initial_rows);
    if(jQuery('#add_product_product_attribute_id').length > 0)
        id_combination = jQuery('#add_product_product_attribute_id').val();

    interval = setInterval(function(){ 

        if(i >= 5000)
        {

            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            rows = jQuery('#orderProducts tbody tr').length;

            if(rows > initial_rows)
            {

                i = 10000;
                var response_z = $.ajax({ type: "POST",   
                            url: aem_ajax,  
                            cache: false,
                            data: {  action: 'add_product_to_order', id_product: product_id, price_tax_excl: price_tax_excl, price_tax_incl:price_tax_incl, qty:qty, id_combination: id_combination,   id_order: aem_id_order, id_employee: aem_id_employee, token: aem_token }, 
                            async: true,
                            success: function(data) {


                            }

                            }).responseText;



            }


        }




        i = i + 100;
    }, 100);

    return false;
});



jQuery('.delete_product_line').click(function(){
            console.log('xxxxx2');
});

jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete_product_line', function(){


    console.log('xxxxx');
    var parent = jQuery(this).closest('tr');
    var id_order_detail = parent.find('.edit_product_id_order_detail').val();

    var price_tax_excl = parent.find('.edit_product_price_tax_excl').val();
    var price_tax_incl = parent.find('.edit_product_price_tax_incl').val();
    var qty = parent.find('.edit_product_quantity').val();
    var id_combination = 0;

    var link = 'https://mytestsite.com/'+parent.find('a:eq(0)').attr('href');
    var url = new URL(link);
    var id_product = url.searchParams.get("id_product");

    var response_z = $.ajax({ type: "POST",   
                url: aem_ajax,  
                cache: false,
                data: {  action: 'remove_product_from_order', id_order_detail: id_order_detail, id_order: aem_id_order, id_product: id_product, id_employee: aem_id_employee,qty: qty, price_tax_excl:price_tax_excl, price_tax_incl:price_tax_incl,  token: aem_token }, 
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {


                }

                }).responseText;

    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/n3uhe2sy/1/

Comment: If the first one works, there is no reason why the second one wouldn't: please post a minimal, concrete and verifiable example where you can actually reproduce your problem. I am suspecting that there are other interfering logic in your code, such as `.off()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` working.

Comment: the second one will fail if it runs before the body exists (such as in the `<head>`)

Comment: I see no reason that this wouldn't work, other than if the target element was in an iframe and the code above was running in the parent document. Otherwise, you simply haven't provided enough information.

Comment: I have edited the main post, with a full example, the problem does not make seance to me eighter

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where what you are describing is possible given your code.

Answer (score -1):

Use `document` instead of `'body'` in this case.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete_product_line', function(){ 
        console.log('ccccc');
    });
})
```

Comment: @KevinB you're right, I was just adapting it to OP's code.